# How to display the column footer before the summary band in jasper reprots

Tags: jasper-reports

I am working with jasper reports-4.5.0.I have to display the column footer immediately after the last line of the detail band.But in my report it is printing after the summary band.I have tried with the solutions provided in google like setting isFloatColumnFooter to true.But it does not solves the problem.Can any one help me regarding this.

Thank You.

Comment: Why you want to summary below than column footer. Can you post jrxml file.

Comment: I am using groups in my report.I am priting a line for bottom border when group gets changed.It is fine.But the problem is for the last group it is not printing the line so the report is not looking good with out bottom border. So i am trying to add a line in column footer.It is printing the line but it is coming after the summary band.But i want column footer immediately after detail band.I can make the summary band height to zero but in my report i need to use summary also.Any help is appreciated or any alternative is also appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed by doing subreport. Please make sure subreport is invoking from parent summary band and all detail, column footer bands should go in subreport and make sure put summary band should be in LastPageFooter band.